# Canned auto email forward (with attachments) in Outlook 2013

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, vba, microsoft-outlook-2013

I get emails sent into me from one sender (with attachments). All I do is forward (not reply) that email to another recipient with a short sentence (always the same).

Surely this could be automated .... any assistance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short how-to (Outlook 2013 and 2016)

- Open Outlook and select File from the top menu.
- Select Manage Rules & Alerts.
- Select the email address you want to apply the rule to if you have multiple addresses.
- Select New Rule and Start From A Blank Rule.
- Select Apply rule on messages I receive.
- Select your condition. Here you set whether you forward emails from certain people or only those marked as important or some other condition depending on your needs.
- Select the link for each condition you select to refine it further. Enter a corresponding value to match what you’re looking to do.
- Select the Forward It To People Or Public Group option in the next window. Select the link and add the email address of the email address you want emails forwarded to.
- Check the details in the final box and select Next if happy.
- Create an exception if necessary. This would exclude certain emails or spam from being forwarded.
- Name your forwarding rule and select to Turn on this rule when you’re ready.

One warning: If the recepient of the forwarded mail just presses reply you will get the mail and not the original sender.

Comment: where do I add the body of the email in the forward?

Comment: ?? The whole mail is forwarded including all headers and attachments - without VBA or similar Add-On tools you can only forward the complete package

Comment: Sorry maybe I was unclear - I want to forward the email but I want to add my own comments in as well. My own comments are just indicating what to do with the email - and they are always the same. So I need a way to forward it with what I've written in the forwarded email body

Comment: So if you have already opened and read it how should it then auto-forward? The workaround is create a "special" folder and whats dropped into it, is sent to a specific address. But for automatic text enhancements you need third party tools

Comment: Thing is I don't need to open and read it - anything that comes in from this specific email address just gets passed on. example: It's a submission email for projects that gets sent to me. I then forward it to a different email and say who it's for and what type of business (it's always the same) .. it's extremely inefficient and I act as a middleman for no real reason

Comment: You have two options - third party tools/VBA or different mailboxes to send to (depending on sender and/or subject)

Answer (score 0):

As I know, I am afraid that we could not automatic add texts  could not be achieved with the functions of the Outlook client alone.

As a workaround, you may try to set the short sentence as your signature when when forwarding messages. However, this may casue inconvenience for you when replying or forward messages to other users. If possile, it is suggested to use a mailbox which you do not use frequently to complete this task.

Answer (score 0):

Not truly/fully automated but Quick steps can do the forwarding - adding the standardized body to the new email.
You still have to highlight the email, then select the quick step.

I agree it would be nice if this could be fully automated (without a VBA script)